# I am having trouble getting the ls command file back

Tags: linux, bash

I want to move `/bin/ls` to `/root`, but I typed a wrong dir:

```
mv /bin/ls /roo
```

Now I couldn't find the `ls` command file, how can I retrieve it?

Comment: try this : mv /roo /bin/ls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, why do you want to do that??  Careful with root privilege!!

Unless you have an *extremely* good reason and know exactly what you're doing, don't move unix commands from /bin. For one thing, other OS components and libraries may depend on them and you could totally hose your system.

ls is used from various binaries in subprocesses to list files.

Do this to recover, if you're sure what you're showing here is what you did to move it exactly.

```
mv /roo /bin/ls
```

Comment: Thank you,I get it . Now it recovers. I am new in Linux, I just want a try to make commands perform in any directories by adding a directory to PATH . I think i should be more careful. (sorry for my poor English,I'm trying to learn well it)

Comment: You're doing fine. Everyone has to start somewhere. At least you're trying stuff.  :-) Have you heard of VMWare or VirtualBox or Parallels?  They are ways you can create UNIX systems on your PC or Mac but you can easily create snapshots and back them up and protect yourself if you slip up and recover. They make it very convenient to configure many different systems. VirtualBox is free!